# Sharing Memory in Gunicorn?

Tags: python, flask, networkx, gunicorn

I have a large read-only data structure (a graph loaded in networkx, though this shouldn't be important) that I use in my web service. The webservice is built in Flask and then served through Gunicorn. Turns out that for every gunicorn worker I spin up, that worked holds its own copy of my data-structure. Thus, my ~700mb data structure which is perfectly manageable with one worker turns into a pretty big memory hog when I have 8 of them running. Is there any way I can share this data structure between gunicorn processes so I don't have to waste so much memory?

Comment: Have you considered using something like Redis to store the data and access it from each process? Would be very similar to shared memory as far as speed goes.

Comment: I would, but we're talking about a complex graph that there's no easy way to store in Redis (Redis has no directed edge graphs or general graph support currently AFAIK).

Comment: Did the solution work for you? If yes can you le me know in detail, how you did it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It looks like the easiest way to do this is to [tell gunicorn to preload your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213619/sharing-a-lock-between-gunicorn-workers) using the [`preload_app`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#preload-app) option.  This assumes that you can load the data structure as a module-level variable:

```
from flask import Flask
from your.application import CustomDataStructure

CUSTOM_DATA_STRUCTURE = CustomDataStructure('/data/lives/here')

# @app.routes, etc.
```

Alternatively, you could use a [memory-mapped file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854594/sharing-static-global-data-among-processes-in-a-gunicorn-flask-app) (if you can wrap the shared memory with your custom data structure), [gevent with gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854594/sharing-static-global-data-among-processes-in-a-gunicorn-flask-app) to ensure that you're only using one *process*, or [the multi-processing module to spin up your own data-structure server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366124/share-a-numpy-array-in-gunicorn-processes) which you connect to using IPC.

Comment: preload option is not working, can you provide some example of how to use it with some dummy data structure?

Comment: @neel - you're probably better off asking another question with an example of your setup and what's not working.

Comment: I have posted the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914587/how-to-get-a-concurreny-of-1000-requests-with-flask-and-gunicorn 
It would be great if you look at it once. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A great read, although didn't help me setup catch the parent process while using a Uvicorn worker, but I managed to stumble upon a solution that I think is even cleaner than the preload method, and it's using a python config file for gunicorn. `-c gconfig.py`